# Как изменить адресную строку браузера без перезагрузки?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сайт у меня на аяксе и нужно чтобы при кликании по ссылке сработал аякс (то есть страница не перезагружается, а подгружается), делаю так:

```
location.href=bla-bla;
return false;
```

но как я и думал - это не сработало. Какие есть решения? То есть нужно в адрессную строку вставить урл той ссылки, на которую кликается пользователем.

Comment: Можно попробовать посмотреть тут:
https://github.com/kapitonoval2012/Js-Url-Edit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function setLocation(curLoc){
    try {
      history.pushState(null, null, curLoc);
      return;
    } catch(e) {}
    location.hash = '#' + curLoc;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: Добрый день.

Можно ли как то реализовать перемещение по той истории с помощью браузерных кнопок вперед/назад? Сейчас при нажатие на кнопку "назад" меняется URl, но перемещения не происходит

Comment: @MrFranke так вам по идее нужно отлавливать это событие (изменение url)

Comment: Почему try - catch вместо проверки?

Answer (score 8):

```
  window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

> Спецификация HTML5 также определяет другой, более сложный и более
>   надежный способ управления историей посещений, основанный на использовании
>   метода `history.pushState()` и события `popstate`. При переходе в новое состояние веб-приложение может вызвать метод `history.pushState()`, чтобы добавить это состояние в историю посещений.
>
> В первом аргументе методу передается объект, содержащий всю информацию, необходимую для восстановления текущего состояния приложения. Для этой цели подойдет любой объект, который можно преобразовать в строку вызовом метода `JSON.stringify()`, а также некоторые встроенные типы, такие как `Date` и `RegExp`.
>
> Во втором аргументе передается необязательное заглавие (простая текстовая строка), которую броузер сможет использовать для идентификации сохраненного состояния в истории посещений (например, в меню кнопки Back).
>
> В третьем необязательном аргументе передается строка URL, которая будет отображаться как адрес текущего состояния. Относительные URL-адреса интерпретируются относительно текущего адреса документа и нередко определяют лишь часть URL, соответствующую идентификатору фрагмента, такую как `#state`.
>
> Связывание различных состояний приложения с собственными URL-адресами дает пользователю возможность делать закладки на внутренние состояния приложения, и если в строке URL будет указан достаточное количество информации, приложение сможет восстановить это состояние при запуске с помощью закладки.
>
> © Дэвид Флэнаган. "JavaScript. Подробное руководство"

Именно этим API пользуется, например, Вконтакте - адрес страниц меняется полностью без `#`.

Стоит отметить, что `window.history...` писать не обязательно, достаточно просто `history...`. Также надо упомянуть, что данный API работает не во всех браузерах, например, как сказано в [аналогичном вопросе на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997181/how-could-i-change-windows-location-without-reloading-and-hack), в IE9 его нет.

Answer (score 2):

Работает даже в IE8:

```
function setLocation(curLoc){
  location.href = curLoc;
  location.hash = curLoc;
}
```

Только функцию я вызываю с хешем:

```
setLocation('#book/' + id);
```