# Как реализован в SPA на VUE JS передача параметров из input или из формы?

Tags: vue.js, spa

Вот есть сайт обычный, там форма которая при GET submit перезагружает страницу и в URL попадают параметры запроса типо www.site.com/search?name=valu....
Как реализован в SPA на VUE JS такое? Только без перезагрузки? Как в ВК к примеру. Кто нибудь знает что я имею в виду и где почитать информацию по этому делу

Comment: запрос отправляется через Ajax, но при этом в адресную строку записываются данные, без ее перезагрузки

Comment: да, 100% Ajax, вот только как эти данные передать сразу в строку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85380/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот примерно так. Юзай `v-model`. `axios` это, конечно, опционально. Можно фечем забирать, или xhr обычным. Главное, чтобы переменная, которая связана с инпутом, была заполнена. Но очень советую с аксиосом разобраться. Упрощает жизнь.
PS: код не выполнится. Это для наглядности.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inputValue: '',
  }
  methods: {
    async asyncSend() {
      try {
        await axios.get('/targetUrl');
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <input v-model="inputValue" type="text">
 <p>Тут отобразится значение переменной для отправки: {{inputValue}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ajax понятен, но мой вопрос о передачи параметров запроса в адресную строку без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Не совсем понятна цель. Можете расписать подробнее, чего добиться надо? Конкретно по адресной сроке смотрите на vue router.

Comment: надо чтобы вот как при поиске в вк или https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions, только на VUE js, вводим запрос в input и его параметры передаются в адресную строку