# Преобразование url в адресной строке без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, apache

К сожалению, не смог решить задачу самостоятельно. Прошу помочь разобраться. Тренируюсь на локальном сервере.

> **Задача**
>
> Нужно преобразовать адрес вида:
>
> ```
> http://localhost/site/users/profile
> ```
>
> в адрес вида:
>
> ```
> http://localhost/site/users/tol64
> ```
>
> , но без перезагрузки страницы.

//---

Сейчас реализовано так, что при наведении курсора на ссылку показывается адрес

```
http://localhost/site/users/tol64
```

, но переход осуществляется по

```
http://localhost/site/users/profile.php
```

То есть в **html** вместо **profile** в ссылку подставляется никнейм авторизованного пользователя:

```
<a class="profile" href="/site/users/<?php echo @$_SESSION['logged_user']; ?>">
```

, а при обработке клика по ссылке в **javascript** подменяем ссылку для перехода к нужному **php**-скрипту:

```
const user_link = document.querySelector('.profile');
if (user_link != undefined) {
    user_link.onclick = function() {
        this.href = 'http://localhost/site/users/profile';
    };
}
```

В файле **.htaccess** есть преобразование убирающее расширение **.php**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Перепробовал множество различных вариантов. Ничего не помогает.
Либо всё остаётся, как есть. Либо ошибка 404.

Одна из попыток приводящая к ошибке 404:

```
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ /profile?user=$1
```

А вот этот вариант ошибок не выдаёт, но ничего не изменяет в адресной строке:

```
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)$ /profile?user=$1
```

Файл **.htaccess** находится в корневой директории:

```
http://localhost/site
```

Как можно решить эту задачу? Может быть есть другие способы без редактирования **.htaccess**?

**P.S. >**

Попробовал применить предложенные в других темах решения. К сожалению это не дало нужно результата. Опишу, что сделал и что получил на этот раз.

В файле **.htaccess** теперь не производится попытки преобразования ссылки.

JS-код обработки клика на ссылке профиля пользователя теперь выглядит вот так:

```
const user_link = document.querySelector('.profile');
if (user_link != undefined) {
    user_link.onclick = function() {
        //--- Получаем никнейм из содержания элемента
        let user_name = this.innerText;
        //--- Блокируем переход по ссылке
        this.href = '#';
        //--- Добавляем в историю путь, который нужно отобразить в адресной строке
        window.history.pushState(null, null, "/site/users/" + user_name);
        //--- Подготовка запроса для сервера
        var xhr = AjaxRequest();
        //--- Путь к файлу с содержимым профиля
        let path = '/site/users/profile';
        //--- Асинхронный (true) GET-запрос для *.php
        xhr.open("GET", path, true);
        //--- Ожидаемый тип ответа
        xhr.responseType = 'text';
        //--- Запрос данных
        xhr.send();
        //--- Обработка ответа от сервера
        xhr.onload = function () {
            //--- Вернуться в истории на шаг назад
            window.history.back();
            //--- Переписать страницу присланным html-кодом от сервера
            document.write(xhr.response);
        }
    };
}
```

После нажатия на ссылке профиля пользователя сначала блокируется переход по ней:

```
this.href = '#';
```

и, если при обработке ответа от сервера не произвести шаг назад:

```
window.history.back();
```

, то в адресной строке увидим следующий результат:

```
http://localhost/site/users/tol64#
```

Шаг назад убирает символ #, но иногда видно, как он мигает.

На первый взгляд проблема решена, но если сейчас, находясь в профиле пользователя, обновить страницу, получаем ошибку 404.

Есть ли, какие-то общие правила, которые бы помогли реализовать описанную схему без таких проблем? Может быть, кто-нибудь порекомендует книгу, где описывается подобное, чтобы не изобретать велосипед? На многих сайтах такое реализовано.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить адресную строку браузера без перезагрузки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85380/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: *чтобы не изобретать велосипед*, можно воспользоваться одним из фреймворков. Они для того и создавались, чтобы реализовать типовые решения и позволить программисту сконцентрироваться на конкретной прикладной задаче. Обычно это осознают только после N-й попытки написать собственный фреймворк (я, кстати, - не исключение). Обратите внимание, например, на Laravel, IMHO он легче для начала. И там это есть. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters

Comment: А если создать страницу с адресом http://localhost/site/users/tol64, и в ней <iframe width=100% height=100% src="http://localhost/site/users/profile"></iframe>?