# Модальные окна в SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Vue JS. Есть таблица со списком работников. При нажатии на работника открывается модальное окно с детальной информации о нём. Всё так и работает. Но необходимо, чтобы существовала ссылка для работника. Сама таблица доступна по роуту:

> /peoples/10/1

Хотелось бы, чтобы при открытии модального окна ссылка превращалась в:

> /peoples/10/1/show/551

Для этого я сделал вот такой конфиг, c props=true:

> /peoples/:type/:company?(/show/)?:peopleId?

И всё впринципе работает. Только вот не знаю как передать /show/ в

> router.push({name:'Peoples', params...})

Также потом я придумал способ с children route. Родительским будет являться сам Peoples, а просмотр конкретного работника это его дочерний роут (и компонент для него с модалкой). Но всё равно остаётся проблема с URL, с этим /show/. Можно ли как то для дочерних роутов делать, чтобы они наследовали path у родителя?

Или может вообще всё можно сделать проще?

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы при открытии этого урла `/peoples/10/1/show/551` отобразился компонент с открытым модальным окном?

Comment: Да, с самой модалкой проблем нет

Comment: в принципе,  данные в адресную строку можно добавить и без роутера, а по закрытию окна - удалить их

Comment: А как ? Просто сделать window.location.href += ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85380/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Всё-таки сделал через children route. Думаю это элегантнее. И route наследуется если не ставить слэш в начале. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, в этой ситуации самое правильно делать children view и модальное окно в отдельном Vue компоненте. И добавлять на страницу, где открывается модалка  . При такой схеме не будет вообще никаких проблем связанных с передачей параметров. При закрытии модального окна просто берете parentRoute с текущими параметрами и URL без проблем изменится, при этом родительский компонент не будет перезагружаться.

Если начинать делать изменения в URL в обход Vue, то получатся костыли. И придётся всё продумывать. Если есть инструмент для роутинга, нужно использовать его возможности. Пробовал по-разному, и этот вариант оказался самым не больным. Модальные окна стали просто как отдельным single page, по архитектуре это весьма логично.